# How do I get Siri to recognise devices that work in Home.app

Tags: siri, homekit

I have various Homekit devices that all work with the Home app and until the last week they worked with Siri voice commands. Now Siri can't find them with voice commands, this chnage probably coincides with the release of iOS 15.4

The devices are
Room Bedroom, Name Bedside Lamp. Last month the command that worked was "Hey Siri Bedroom Lamp on" This month this affects the Lamp in my Living Room. (This I fixed in Home app by renaming the device to Lamp)

Room Kitchen, Name Immersion Heater. Last month this worked now Siri says "Sorry .. I could not find anything like that in your home"

How can I make Siri understand what devices are called.

How can I make Siri give the names of devices it knows. "Hey Siri List my devices" tells me I have 9 devices attached"

On another attempt I asked Siri "What devices do I have in my Kitchen" It responded you have "One Outlet : Immersion Heater" So I asked "Turn the outelt on in the Kitchen" and Siri dod this and replied. "Turned Immersion Heater On"

So how does Siri know the name and say it is turned on but will not recognise the name if I say it. Home.app has no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems iOS 15.5 has fixed the immersion heater name issue